# anonymous type object or dynamic

Tags: c#, linq

Assuming we have a function:

```
public IEnumerable<object> GetViewModel(int id) {
            var records = LoadRecordById(id);    
            var result = (from record in records
                select new {
                    field1 = record.data1,
                    field2 = record.data2,
                    ....
                }).ToArray();    
            return result;
        }
```

We can return it like `IEnumerable<object>` and like `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. The question is: what to use and why? what advantages/disadvantages ?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21080346/difference-between-object-dynamic-and-var

Comment: Look into the differences between `object` and `dynamic` and you have your answer. Consider creating a named type instead -- anonymous types are not meant to be used like this.

Comment: IMHO create an interface or a base class; this violates basic OO principles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an anonymous type right now.

If you cast it to `object`, you will have no way to get the fields out.  You cannot cast it back to an anonymous object (since you don't know what it was) and you can't access the properties from `object`.

If you cast it to `dynamic`, you can access the fields as you normally would, but you will lose all type safety.  It will determine the type at compile time, which means you have access to the types generated at compile time, but if you type something wrong you will get a compilation error at runtime.

Best thing to do is to create a class that has the properties you need and return a list of that class.  Then you will get the properties, and will get the benefits of static typing.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an interface or a base class. But to answer your question:

```
dynamic foo = "Some string";
foo.ToUpper(); // this works fine
foo.Something(); // compiles, but runtime error

object bar = "Some string";
bar.ToUpper(); // does not compile
```